# Numbering polygons according to starting point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, numbering, sequential

I need to number the polygons in a certain order in QGIS 3.26. A good solution is the command according to @Babel's solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/417062/218260, but if the line crosses the polygon more than once, the numbering of the polygon is sometimes wrong, see the attachment.

```sql
array_find ( 
   array_sort( 
        array_filter(  
            array_agg(  
                line_locate_point( 
                    overlay_crosses(
                        'line', 
                        $geometry
                    )[0],
                    array_foreach (
                        overlay_crosses(
                            'line', 
                            $geometry
                        ),
                        centroid (
                            intersection ($geometry, @element)
                        )
                    )[0]
                )
            ), 
            @element > 0
        )
    ),
    line_locate_point( 
        overlay_crosses(
            'line', 
            $geometry
        )[0],
        array_foreach (
            overlay_crosses('line', $geometry),
            centroid (intersection ($geometry, @element)
        )
    )[0]
    )
)+1
```

[image]

Or do you know another way to number the polygons in any order without having to manually enter the number?

Comment: Have a look at this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436427/incremented-index-on-a-split-polyline-in-qgis/436443#436443), though you would probably also have to filter for the minimum found index when there is multiple line-polygon intersection. If all fails, see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437424/adding-a-number-by-clicking-on-polygon-in-qgis/437428#437428) for a way of numbering the polygons by clicking on them

Answer (score 2):

First create a field (I'll call it distance), that stores the distance from the star point of the linear geometry to the first intersection with the polygon.

```
with_variable(
  'line',
  overlay_intersects('line_layer', $geometry)[0], -- put inside quoted line layer name/id
  length(
    array_filter(
      geometries_to_array(difference(@line, $geometry)),
      touches(point_n(@line, 1), @element)
    )[0]
  )
)
```

Then, calculate a new field numbering in ascending order the result of the `distance` field.

```
array_find(
  array_agg(
    "distance",
    order_by:="distance"
  ),
  "distance"
)
```

Replace wherever `"distance"` appears with  the name of the field calculated with the first expression.

Comment: First command does not work. I am sending a picture in the attachment.

Do I need to change 'line_layer' or 'line' according to my line name?


https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYpdP.jpg

Comment: @dysano, Yes, there was an error with a function name, I already fix it.